# Can run online https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_jsonp_php but cannot run on my computer

Tags: php, jsonp

The example at : https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_jsonp_php
But when I copy it to my computer, It did not work

The error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
I vitsit this site: https://idiallo.com/javascript/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token#n. They advice to use ajax but I still want to use create "script" tag (`document.createElement("script")`)because JSONP allow to use

First file: json_demo_db.php, second file:Call_JSON.php
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O1IeNWi45VchP2LxZ8RLlXCdKbO9DaGe/view?usp=sharing

My database: gcom, table:customers(id,name)

Please help me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I adjust file jsonp_demo_db.php as follow

```
<?php   
    header("Content-Type: text/json, application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    //$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gcom");
    //$result = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM ".$obj->$table." LIMIT ".$obj- 
    >$limit);
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM customers LIMIT 10");
    $outp = array();
    $outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo "myFunc(".json_encode($outp).")";
    ?>
```

So It can run independent and result is:
myFunc([{"name":"Messi"},{"name":"Ronaldo"}]) 
so I wonder we should wire json data to file and read the file and tranfer it to json data